# Cannot connect to SQL Server Express 2014 from ArcMap 10.1?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap, sql-server

I have ArcMap 10.1 and SQL Server Express 2014. I am trying to add a database server from ArcMap by following Arcmap>Catalog>Add database server>.

But the connection is not being established. as far as i know the server\sqlinstance name are correct. Is there something else I am missing?

Comment: Have you checked to see I dc SQL-Server 2014 is supported by any Esri product, much less an older one?

Answer (score 3):

Indeed as @Vince suggests only SQL Server 2008 and 2012 are supported by ArcGIS [10.1](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/system-requirements/10.1/index.html#//015100000070000000) (same for [10.2](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/system-requirements/10.2/index.html#//015100000070000000)).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to make a database connection, not a database server one. Also it was my understanding that SQL Server Express instances were named instances and therefore your instance name should be "MYSQLSERVER". As the other users have pointed out SQL Server 2014 isn't officially supported I wouldn't be surprised if a connection can still be made.